# Iterating a JSON Object in angular is looping many times

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON as shown below and I am trying to iterate using ng-repeat the problem is it is not looping once which is what I expect.But it is iterating as many times as the keys in the JSON.
JSON

```
{
    "firstName": ["dsfdsf", "text"],
    "lastName": ["sdfdsfdsf", "text"],
    "email": ["", "email"],
    "homePhone": ["", "tel"],
    "cellPhone": ["", "tel"],
    "birthday": ["", "date"],
    "website": ["", "url"],
    "address": ["", "text"]
}
```

My HTML Code is

```
<div ng-repeat='contact in contacts track by $index' >
        jjj   {{contact.firstName}}
 </div>
```

Result is

jjj

jjj

jjj

jjj

jjj

jjj

jjj

jjj

Please help.

Comment: display `{{ contacts | json  }}` before the ngRepeat to see what is inside

Comment: is contacts an array of objects or just an object? If it is the latter it is normal to behave like that.

Comment: You are iterating over object properties which are firstName, lastname...

That's why you have 8 "jjj". 

Just do this :

{{contacts.firstName}}

Comment: ng-repeat iterating object for each properties in objet.You need to form array of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your array of contacts is incorrect

try something like this:

```
contacts: [
  {
    "firstName": ["dsfdsf", "text"],
    "lastName": ["sdfdsfdsf", "text"],
    "email": ["", "email"],
    "homePhone": ["", "tel"],
    "cellPhone": ["", "tel"],
    "birthday": ["", "date"],
    "website": ["", "url"],
    "address": ["", "text"]
  }
];
```

but keep in mind that your array structure will change to something like this:

```
contacts: [
 0: {
    "firstName": ["dsfdsf", "text"],
    ...
  },
 1 : {
     "firstName": ["dsfdsf", "text"],
    ...
  } ,
  ...
];
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate a object you need to use this syntax

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

plunker

> http://plnkr.co/edit/MOuQmpIQmWgwyGMQyO7p

[angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)